# Is there a PHP function which when given two arrays returns only the indexes which keys match the other?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looking for a more efficient way of doing the following but preferentially without a for/while loop.

```
  $contacts_needed = array('tom','joe');

  $all_contacts = array(
      'tom'  => array('age'=>20, 'sex'=>'m'),
      'jack' => array('age'=>33, 'sex'=>'f'),
      'rob'  => array('age'=>33, 'sex'=>'m'),
      'joe'  => array('age'=>33, 'sex'=>'m'),
      'jill' => array('age'=>20, 'sex'=>'f'),
  );

  $contacts = array();

  foreach ($contacts_needed  as $contacts_name) {
    $contacts[$contacts_name] = in_array($contacts_name,$all_contacts) ? $all_contacts[$contacts_name] : array();
  }
```

Is there a function which already does this? 
e.g

```
  $contacts = array_functionname($contacts_needed, $all_contacts);
   //array_in_array(needles, haystack);
```

if not is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php?

Comment: brilliant ill try to rephrase the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so with [`array_intersect_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php)

```
$contacts_needed = array('tom','joe');

$all_contacts = array(
    'tom'  => array('age'=>20, 'sex'=>'m'),
    'jack' => array('age'=>33, 'sex'=>'f'),
    'rob'  => array('age'=>33, 'sex'=>'m'),
    'joe'  => array('age'=>33, 'sex'=>'m'),
    'jill' => array('age'=>20, 'sex'=>'f'),
);

$contacts = array_intersect_key($all_contacts, array_flip($contacts_needed));

print_r($contacts);
```

`$contacts` now holds

```
Array
(
    [tom] => Array
    (
        [age] => 20
        [sex] => m
    )

    [joe] => Array
    (
        [age] => 33
        [sex] => m
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is :

```
array_intersect_key($arrayToFilter, array_flip($simpleArrayOfKeys))
```

You can see a detailed example on PHP site: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-intersect-key.php#109706